# How can I copy extracted text page by page in a document to a new PDF document with PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I want to copy the text of an original PDF document into a new PDF document preserving the formatting of the source text.

I have already done some tests, but the result of copying the text
into the new document is not I hoped. Below I show code in the
content stream.

```js
for (PDPage page : newDoc.getPages()) {
     PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(newDoc, page);
     contentStream.beginText(); 
     for(List<TextLine> row : rowList){
         for(TextLine characters : line){
             contentStream.setFont(characters.getFont(),               characters.getFontSize());          
             contentStream.newLineAtOffset(characters.getxPos(), characters.getyPos());
             contentStream.setLeading(10.5f);
             contentStream.showText(characters.getText());
          }
      }
      contentStream.endText();
      contentStream.close();
}
```

Comment: If you want to copy text with positions and style, I'd propose copying the operations in the content stream and the resources used. Extracting text will give you only part of the information, and even that with some loss.

Comment: I edited the post showing the result of my tests. You can consult it and advise me better on what to do.

Comment: You're mixing absolute and relative coordinates. `characters.getxPos()` and `characters.getyPos()` are absolute coordinates while `contentStream.newLineAtOffset` requires relative coordinates: coordinates relative to where the previous `contentStream.newLineAtOffset` pointed. Also you are mixing different coordinates systems. `characters.getxPos()` and `characters.getyPos()` are coordinates in a system with the origin at the top left and the y coordinate increasing downwards. `contentStream.newLineAtOffset` on the other hand usually has the y coordinate increasing upwards.

Comment: Thanks for this observation, how do I get the relative coordinates of the text in the source pdf document?

Comment: *"how do I get the relative coordinates of the text in the source pdf document"* - by subtracting the previous absolute coordinates from the current absolut ones you get the current ones relative to the previous `contentStream.newLineAtOffset` call.

Comment: By previous absolute coordinates do you mean the coordinates of the text in the source document and by current coordinates those in the destination document?

Comment: You iterate over `line`. By previous absolute coordinates i mean those of the previous `TextLine characters`.

Comment: Could you give me a practical example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Copying the text

We already discussed your approach in the comments to your question and you eventually asked for a *practical example*.

Unfortunately your code is not compilable, let alone runnable, so I had to create somewhat different code:

```java
void copyText(PDDocument source, int sourcePageNumber, PDDocument target, PDPage targetPage) throws IOException {
    List<TextPosition> allTextPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
        @Override
        protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
            allTextPositions.addAll(textPositions);
            super.writeString(text, textPositions);
        }
    };
    pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(sourcePageNumber + 1);
    pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(sourcePageNumber + 1);
    pdfTextStripper.getText(source);

    PDRectangle targetPageCropBox = targetPage.getCropBox();
    float yOffset = targetPageCropBox.getUpperRightY() + targetPageCropBox.getLowerLeftY();

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(target, targetPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
        contentStream.beginText();
        float x = 0;
        float y = yOffset;
        for (TextPosition position: allTextPositions) {
            contentStream.setFont(position.getFont(), position.getFontSizeInPt());
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(position.getX() - x, - (position.getY() - y));
            contentStream.showText(position.getUnicode());
            x = position.getX();
            y = position.getY();
        }
        contentStream.endText();
    }
}
```

You can apply it to a full document like this:

```java
void copyText(PDDocument source, PDDocument target) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < source.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PDPage sourcePage = source.getPage(i);
        PDPage targetPage = null;
        if (i < target.getNumberOfPages())
            targetPage = target.getPage(i);
        else
            target.addPage(targetPage = new PDPage(sourcePage.getMediaBox()));
        copyText(source, i, target, targetPage);
    }
}
```

Applied to some example documents one gets:

| Original | Copy |
| --- | --- |
| [image: input.pdf] | [image: input-TextCopy.pdf] |
| [image: TemplateTank.pdf] | [image: TemplateTank-TextCopy.pdf] |
| [image: test_document_signed.pdf] | [image: test_document_signed-TextCopy.pdf] |

As is to be expected, "text" that actually is drawn as bitmap image, is not copied.

Also beware, this is just a proof of concept and not a complete implementation. In particular page rotation and non-upright text in general are not supported. Also the only supported style attributes are text font and text size, other details (e.g. text color) are ignored. Different page geometries in source and target also will result in weird appearances.

## Manipulating the text

In a comment you asked

> If I wanted to replace some words in the source document with others in the target document and then format it, how could I modify the code?

To replace some glyphs while keeping everything else in place, is fairly easy. The `TextPosition` instances in `allTextPositions` are sorted the same way as the normal text output of the `PdfTextStripper` is. To find certain words, therefore, you simply can search `allTextPositions` for sequences of `TextPosition` instances whose texts.

To allow for this, I extended the above methods to additionally accept a `Consumer` that is called between retrieval and drawing:

```java
void copyText(PDDocument source, PDDocument target, Consumer<List<TextPosition>> updater) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0; i < source.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        PDPage sourcePage = source.getPage(i);
        PDPage targetPage = null;
        if (i < target.getNumberOfPages())
            targetPage = target.getPage(i);
        else
            target.addPage(targetPage = new PDPage(sourcePage.getMediaBox()));
        copyText(source, i, target, targetPage, updater);
    }
}

void copyText(PDDocument source, int sourcePageNumber, PDDocument target, PDPage targetPage, Consumer<List<TextPosition>> updater) throws IOException {
    List<TextPosition> allTextPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    PDFTextStripper pdfTextStripper = new PDFTextStripper() {
        @Override
        protected void writeString(String text, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
            allTextPositions.addAll(textPositions);
            super.writeString(text, textPositions);
        }
    };
    pdfTextStripper.setStartPage(sourcePageNumber + 1);
    pdfTextStripper.setEndPage(sourcePageNumber + 1);
    pdfTextStripper.getText(source);

    if (updater != null)
        updater.accept(allTextPositions);

    PDRectangle targetPageCropBox = targetPage.getCropBox();
    float yOffset = targetPageCropBox.getUpperRightY() + targetPageCropBox.getLowerLeftY();

    try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(target, targetPage, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true)) {
        contentStream.beginText();
        float x = 0;
        float y = yOffset;
        for (TextPosition position: allTextPositions) {
            contentStream.setFont(position.getFont(), position.getFontSizeInPt());
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(position.getX() - x, - (position.getY() - y));
            contentStream.showText(position.getUnicode());
            x = position.getX();
            y = position.getY();
        }
        contentStream.endText();
    }
}
```

*([CopyFormattedPageText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/content/CopyFormattedPageText.java) methods)*

Now there are different strategies for replacing the glyphs. I've implemented two simple ones.

The first strategy replaces a search word in the list of `TextPosition` objects by replacing the letters in each instance by the same number of letters from the replacement word (as long as available). This is appropriate if the word is especially formatted (e.g. spaced out) and this special formatting shall be kept.

```java
void searchAndReplace(List<TextPosition> textPositions, String searchWord, String replacement) {
    if (searchWord == null || searchWord.length() == 0)
        return;

    int candidatePosition = 0;
    String candidate = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < textPositions.size(); i++) {
        candidate += textPositions.get(i).getUnicode();
        if (!searchWord.startsWith(candidate)) {
            candidate = "";
            candidatePosition = i+1;
        } else if (searchWord.length() == candidate.length()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < searchWord.length();) {
                TextPosition textPosition = textPositions.get(candidatePosition);
                int length = textPosition.getUnicode().length();
                String replacementHere = "";
                if (length > 0 && j < replacement.length()) {
                    int end = j + length;
                    if (end > replacement.length())
                        end = replacement.length();
                    replacementHere = replacement.substring(j, end);
                }
                TextPosition newTextPosition = new TextPosition(textPosition.getRotation(),
                        textPosition.getPageWidth(), textPosition.getPageHeight(), textPosition.getTextMatrix(),
                        textPosition.getEndX(), textPosition.getEndY(), textPosition.getHeight(),
                        textPosition.getIndividualWidths()[0], textPosition.getWidthOfSpace(),
                        replacementHere,
                        textPosition.getCharacterCodes(), textPosition.getFont(),
                        textPosition.getFontSize(), (int) textPosition.getFontSizeInPt());
                textPositions.set(candidatePosition, newTextPosition);
                candidatePosition++;
                j += length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*([CopyFormattedPageText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/content/CopyFormattedPageText.java#L182) method)*

The second strategy replaces a search word in the list of `TextPosition` objects by replacing the letters in the first instance by the whole replacement word and removing the other instances. This is appropriate if the word is not specially formatted (e.g. spaced out) and shall be printed naturally.

```java
void searchAndReplaceAlternative(List<TextPosition> textPositions, String searchWord, String replacement) {
    if (searchWord == null || searchWord.length() == 0)
        return;

    int candidatePosition = 0;
    String candidate = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < textPositions.size(); i++) {
        candidate += textPositions.get(i).getUnicode();
        if (!searchWord.startsWith(candidate)) {
            candidate = "";
            candidatePosition = i+1;
        } else if (searchWord.length() == candidate.length()) {
            TextPosition textPosition = textPositions.get(candidatePosition);
            TextPosition newTextPosition = new TextPosition(textPosition.getRotation(),
                    textPosition.getPageWidth(), textPosition.getPageHeight(), textPosition.getTextMatrix(),
                    textPosition.getEndX(), textPosition.getEndY(), textPosition.getHeight(),
                    textPosition.getIndividualWidths()[0], textPosition.getWidthOfSpace(),
                    replacement,
                    textPosition.getCharacterCodes(), textPosition.getFont(),
                    textPosition.getFontSize(), (int) textPosition.getFontSizeInPt());
            textPositions.set(candidatePosition, newTextPosition);

            while (i > candidatePosition) {
                textPositions.remove(i--);
            }
            candidatePosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

*([CopyFormattedPageText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/content/CopyFormattedPageText.java#L232) method)*

You use these strategies like this in your `copyText` calls:

```java
copyText(source, target, list -> searchAndReplace(list, "Test", "Art"));
...
copyText(source, target, list -> searchAndReplaceAlternative(list, "DOCUMENT", "COSTUME"));
```

*([CopyFormattedPageText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox3/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox3/content/CopyFormattedPageText.java#L77) test methods)*

Beware, though, if the fonts used are subset-embedded, the glyphs for the replacement text may not exist in that font. In that case create and use another font that does include the replacement glyphs4. Also the replacement should be as long.

---

As you did not mention a specific PDFBox version, I used the current 3.0.1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried to implement your solution in PDFBox version 2.0.23 and it raises exception to Calibri Bold's f character encoding. It also seems to give me problems with closing the contentStream even though I have closed it. "WARNING: You did not call endText(), some viewers won't display your text Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0066 (f) in font DEVEXP+Calibri,Bold". How can I solve this problem?

Comment: The approach chosen here relies on proper font objects, in particular having proper encoding information. Furthermore, the font must allow roundtrips, Unicode values in the **ToUnicode** table must have values in the **Encoding**. Your document appears to be deficient in that regard.

Comment: Perfect. If I wanted to replace some words in the source document with others in the target document and then format it, how could I modify the code?

Comment: @black__ariel *"If I wanted to replace some words in the source document with others"* - After running the text stripper (i.e. after `pdfTextStripper.getText(source)`) you have all the text in `allTextPositions`. You can search that list for adjacent `TextPosition` objects that form one of the words you're after, and then replace them with ones that hold your replacement letters. Beware, though, if the fonts used are subset-embedded, the replacement may not exist in that font. In that case add and use another font that does include the replacement. Also the replacement should be as long.

Comment: Updated topic, if it's not correct could you give me more details?

Comment: @black__ariel *"Updated topic, if it's not correct could you give me more details?"* - have you tested your changed code?

Comment: If I search for the word to replace it doesn't replace it but shows me blank sheets where it isn't present. I'm going through hard times :(

Comment: Well, I don't even see a variable `text` at that level in your code, so I'm surprised that your code compiles at all. Apparently you have some variable of that name higher up. Nonetheless, *"If I search for the word to replace it doesn't replace it"* - well, obviously. You manipulate some variable `text` that is unconnected to the `TextPosition` objects that carry the characters that are drawn... Also *"shows me blank sheets where it isn't present."* - equally obvious, you only draw text on the target page if `text.contains(searchWord)`.

Comment: So as mentioned above, you have to search the list `allTextPositions` for adjacent `TextPosition` objects whose concatenated respective `getUnicode()` values  form one of the words you're after, and then replace those `TextPosition` objects with copies holding your replacement letters instead of the letters of the search word.

Comment: I tried but without success, could you show me the code?

Comment: *"I tried but without success, could you show me the code?"* - I've added some code for replacing text to my answer.

Comment: Good, but unfortunately it doesn't replace all the letters of the searched word with those of the new one, it leaves the last letters uncovered.

Comment: Please supply examples (PDFs + what you replace by what) to reproduce your issues as I couldn't observe them in my tests.

Comment: Yes, I give an example in my original post.

Comment: @black__ariel *"Yes, I give an example in my original post."* - I see you added images but to reproduce your issue I'd need the _PDFs_ (before and after replacement), the code variant you used (in my answer there are two example strategies, and you might easily have used a different one), and which string you tried to replace by which.