# How to remove specific pattern text from PDF using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a PDF with place holder tags {{place_holder}}. How to remove all occurrence of such tag in the document using PDFBox library.

Sample PDF: https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample/blob/main/sample_tag.pdf

[image]

Tried this [example](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RemoveText.java) but did not work for me.

```
@Override
protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
    String recentText = recentChars.toString();
    recentChars.setLength(0);


    String operatorString = operator.getName();

    if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString) && "{{full_name}}".equals(recentText))
    {
        return;
    }

    super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
}
```

--- Update 1 ---

With below code, it is working as expected for file shared above. But it does not work with similar file generated with Microsoft word export as PDF. [Here](https://github.com/nofelkad/pdf-sample/blob/main/text_tag.pdf) is the file which did not work.

In my case pdf can be generated on any system. So I am looking for more of a generic solution.

```
PdfContentStreamEditor editor = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
    @Override
    protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
        String operatorString = operator.getName();
        if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString))
        {
            if(operands.get(0) instanceof COSString ){
                COSString str= (COSString) operands.get(0);
                String text=str.getString();
                String updated= extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces(text);
                if(!text.equals(updated)){
                    str.setValue(updated.getBytes());
                }
            }
            if(operands.get(0) instanceof COSArray ){
                Iterator var7 =  ((COSArray) operands.get(0)).iterator();
                while(var7.hasNext()) {
                    COSBase obj = (COSBase) var7.next();
                    if (obj instanceof COSString) {
                        COSString str= (COSString) obj;
                        String text=str.getString();
                        String updated= extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces(text);
                        str.setValue(updated.getBytes());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
    }
    final List<String> TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("Tj", "'", "\"", "TJ");
};
editor.processPage(page);



public static String extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces(String input) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{[^}]*\\}\\}|\\{\\{.*$");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        String replacement = " ".repeat(match.length()+7);
        input= input.replace(match,replacement);
    }

    pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*?\\}\\}");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String match = matcher.group();
        String replacement = " ".repeat(match.length()+7);
        input= input.replace(match,replacement);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: The [example](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RemoveText.java) you refer to references [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66815870/1729265), and there you can read: "Beware, though, this only works if the text to remove is drawn using one text showing instruction only and that instruction only draws the text to remove." In case of your document, though, is this: **[(I  {{full_name}} employee of {{ company_name}},agr) 18 (ee that I ) ] TJ**

Comment: Thus, as also remarked in that answer: "And if instead the text to replace is only part of what a single instruction draws, you'll have to doctor around with that instruction. Depending on one's script this may be very difficult, depending on how much it uses ligatures and stuff." Fortunately for you it doesn't use "ligatures and stuff", so it's not really difficult.

Comment: Beware, doctoring around with the instruction will be more difficult in the signature line as there some kerning is applied: **[({{signatur) 18 (e_date}}     {{full_name}}                      {{signatur) 18 (e}}) ] TJ**.

Comment: Thank you @mkl for the detailed explanation. However modifying COSString has its own issue. Explained By you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220165/editing-content-in-pdf-using-pdfbox-removes-last-line-from-pdf)

Comment: *"However modifying COSString has its own issue."* - Oh yes. Your example document still is fairly simple to manipulate, the situation can be much more complicated.

Comment: I find myself stuck with modifying COSString. This approach isn't yielding the expected results, as you rightly pointed out. Would you kindly assist me by providing a brief example to clarify the matter? Your guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
`if(operands.get(0) instanceof COSArray ){.....
 COSString str= (COSString) obj;
 String updatedString = str.getString().replaceAll("\\{\\{.*?\\}\\}"," "); str.setValue(updatedString.getBytes());  } } }`

Comment: *"This approach isn't yielding the expected results"* - what _is_ the expected result, and what _is_ the observed result?

Comment: Expected result is blank space in place of tag which is of same size as tag. What I get is distorted text printed and few tag still intact in the output PDF

Comment: Ok, as far as the "few tag still intact" are concerned, that is clear: In my third comment here I quoted a text showing instruction from your PDF in which the opening `{{` and the closing `}}` are in different strings. Thus, your regular expression won't find them looking for both `{{` and `}}` in the same string, you'll have to also find them in different strings. In your example document they at least are in the same instruction but in general even that is not necessarily the case. Concerning the "distorted text" I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: I have updated the question with the code. While it works seamlessly for the file shared earlier, it encounters difficulties with a similar file generated on a Windows OS. Specifically, the text appears distorted, with boxes replacing characters.

Comment: Ok, as you now have shown your code, it is clear why most of the text is damaged: You make assumptions on the encoding of the `COSString` instances which only seldom are true. You have to take the font into account when decoding or encoding those strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue in your code (that you provided in Update 1) is that you assume some constant, standard encoding of the `COSString` arguments of the text showing operators. This is not the case, according to the specification these arguments shall be interpreted as sequences of character codes according to the encoding of the current PDF font object.

Thus, you should replace the `PdfContentStreamEditor editor` in your code by something like this:

```java
PdfContentStreamEditor editor = new PdfContentStreamEditor(document, page) {
    @Override
    protected void write(ContentStreamWriter contentStreamWriter, Operator operator, List<COSBase> operands) throws IOException {
        String operatorString = operator.getName();
        if (TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS.contains(operatorString))
        {
            PDFont font = getGraphicsState().getTextState().getFont();
            if (operands.get(0) instanceof COSString) {
                COSString str = (COSString) operands.get(0);
                String text = decode(str, font);// str.getString();
                String updated = extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces(text);
                if(!text.equals(updated)){
                    str.setValue(font.encode(updated));//(updated.getBytes());
                }
            }
            if (operands.get(0) instanceof COSArray) {
                Iterator<?> var7 = ((COSArray) operands.get(0)).iterator();
                while (var7.hasNext()) {
                    COSBase obj = (COSBase) var7.next();
                    if (obj instanceof COSString) {
                        COSString str = (COSString) obj;
                        String text = decode(str, font);//str.getString();
                        String updated = extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces(text);
                        str.setValue(font.encode(updated));//(updated.getBytes());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        super.write(contentStreamWriter, operator, operands);
    }

    String decode(COSString string, PDFont font) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(string.getBytes())) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int code = font.readCode(in);
                String chars = font.toUnicode(code);
                builder.append(chars);
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    final List<String> TEXT_SHOWING_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList("Tj", "'", "\"", "TJ");
};
```

*([RemoveText](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox2/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox2/content/RemoveText.java#L158) method `removeTagsLikeVasK`)*

As you see, instead of `updated.getBytes()` now `font.encode(updated)` is used, ensuring that the COS string contains the bytes of `updated` encoded according to the encoding of the font.

Similarly, `str.getString()` is replaced by `decode(str, font)` which decodes the bytes of the COS string according to the font encoding.

With this change in place, the output is not *distorted* anymore.

---

Unfortunately, though, the output is not yet as you want it. The reason is that your `extractStringsBetweenCurlyBraces` method only recognizes that it has to remove something from a given string if it contains a `{{` or a `}}`. But that approach ignores the possibility that a previous string already contained the `{{` and a later string will contain the `}}`.

In your example file created by MS Word, that exact case occurs, it contains e.g. an instruction like this (with character codes replaced by regular text):

```
[(I {{fu) -3 (l) 3 (l) 3 (_n) -3 (ame) -3 (}} e) 5 (mplo) 8 (y) 13 (ee) -3 ( of {{ c) 8 (ompa) -2 (n) 18 (y_n) -3 (am) 5 (e}},agr) 15 (ee) -3 ( tha) 12 (t I wi) 4 (l) 3 (l) 3 (n) ] TJ
```

As you see, `{{full_name}}` for example is split over 6 strings, `I {{fu`, `l`, `l`, `_n`, `ame`, and `}} e`, and your approach will only handle the first and the last of them!

This means that you will have to update your mechanism to keep the state (inside or outside a tag) at the end of one string as starting state of the next one.

Furthermore, even the `{{` and `}}` tag delimiters may be split into separate strings, even more cases to consider.

Alternatively you can try the approach of [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77796703/1729265). While in your current approach you essentially create a near identical copy of the original content stream and manipulate it only a little bit, the approach there gathers the text information from the original and drops the original content stream, building a completely new content stream from the gathered information except the characters to drop.

---

You write:

> In my case pdf can be generated on any system. So I am looking for more of a generic solution.

You can make your solution more generic as outlined above. But there are limits. In particular there are PDF creators whose outputs contain font information that do not allow the roundtrips applied here (decoding the character codes to Unicode and later re-encoding the manipulated Unicode to character codes), or that do not draw the text as text at all (but as arbitrary vector graphics), or make your life difficult in other ways...

---

*I used PDFBox 2.0.28 for the code in this answer.*

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough and clear response! Your explanation really helped me understand. Suggested alternative approach with PDFTextStripper seems more clean solution. I truly appreciate the time and effort you put into crafting such a helpful answer. Thanks again!"